# Having issues centering my text in the drop down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I was able to create a drop down menu, but unable to center the text. Its 
as if padding-left is set but I didn't set it. I just need help centering
the text in the drop down menu.
//drop down menu

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .menu {
        background-color:grey;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .menu li {
        list-style:none;
        padding: 3px;
    }
    .menu a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
    }
    .menu > li {
        display:inline;
    }
    .dropmenu {
        display:none;
        float:right;
        position:relative;
        top:18px;
        left:-422px;
    }
    .dropdown:hover > .dropmenu {
        display:block;
    }
    .dropmenu {
        background-color:grey;
    }


</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul class = "menu">
 <li><a href = "#">HOME</a></li>
 <li><a href = "#">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li class = "dropdown"><a href = "#">SPORTS</a>
   <ul class = "dropmenu">
    <li><a href = "#">NBA</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">NFL</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">MLB</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 <li><a href = "#">CONTACTS</a></li>
 <li><a href = "#">BLOG</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're using `left`, have you tried adjusting that?

Comment: Where are you setting the `text-align:center`?

Answer (score 0):

First, use `text-align: center;` on the dropdown menus. Your dropdown menus will look off center as there is default padding and margin the `ul` you are using for your dropdown menus that browser add by default. You will want to remove that padding/margin from the dropdown `ul`s.

```css
.dropmenu {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

If the dropdown menu becomes too narrow after doing this you'll likely want to set a specific width for your dropdown menus.

```css
.dropmenu {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%; /* same width as containing li */
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7hjqjrjj/2/

*If you're looking to clean up/fix alignment of your dropdown menu read below.*

You want to apply `position: relative;` to the `li`'s that contain a dropdown menu. Then apply `position: absolute;` to that dropdown menu (`ul`). You'll usually add `left: 0;` to the drowpdown menu (`ul`) as well.

Applying `position: relative;` to the containing `li` causes the absolutely positioned dropdown menu to position itself relative to the containing `li`, rather than some place like the top of the page.

We don't want the dropdown to position itself after the anchor tag or other content within the containing `li` so we use absolute positioning.

Update your CSS selectors as follows:

```css
.menu li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 3px;
    position: relative;
}
.dropmenu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 18px;
    left: 0;
}
```

You may need to fiddle with your `top` and `left` values.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7hjqjrjj/1/

Comment: hungerstar, thanks for the tip, it worked. I understood everything except as to why absolute positioned dropdown menu will position itself relative to the containing li.

Comment: An absolute positioned element will position itself relative to the closest positioned element. In your case that is the parent `li` element. If there was no positioned ancestor element and you absolute positioned your dropdown menus with `top: 0;` and `left: 0;` they would all end up in the upper left hand corner of your website, stacking on top of one another. We apply `position: relative;` to the parent so something like that doesn't happen. We do it so it uses the parent elements position in the page as a reference point as to where it should be displayed.